# Mastermind - checking numbers (or colors) in the wrong place (C)

Tags: c

I trying to code mastermind with numbers, 1-6, and I can't do the part where it says how many numbers are in the wrong position. Sometimes it works well, but there are some occasions where it bugs.

Here's an example, if the random number is {5, 2, 3, 3} and the input is {5, 3, 2, 2}, instead of saying "1 right position, 2 wrong position" it says "1 right position, 3 wrong position". Not sure how to fix what I wrote.

```
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){ //rp=rightPlace; wp=wrongPlace; c=code(random); in=input
        if(c[j]==in[j])rp++;
    }
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
        for(i=0;i<4;i++){
            if(c[j]==in[i]){wp++;break;}
        }
    }wp-=rp;
```

On most occasions it works out, but in this one it doesn't. I also understand why it doesn't work, but I can't even think of a way to fix it on paper.

Maybe getting another variable to avoid comparing the same place that was already compared if it has the same value? (in this case it wouldn't compare the second 3 of the code with the only 3 of the input)

almost full code, took the random out

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void){
int c[4],in[4],i,j,ct=0,r,w=0,rp=0,wp=0;
srand(time(NULL));

c[0]=5;
c[1]=2;
c[2]=3;
c[3]=3;

for (i=0;i<4;i++){
    printf("%d ",c[i]);
}printf("\n");

do{
    ct++;
    printf("Try? ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d",&in[0],&in[1],&in[2],&in[3]);
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
        if(c[j]==in[j])rp++;
    }
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
        for(i=0;i<4;i++){
            if(c[i]==in[j]){wp++;break;}
        }
    }
    wp-=rp;
    printf("Right places: %d\nWrong places: %d\n",sc,se);
    if (rp==4){w=1; break;}
    wp=0;rp=0;
}while(w==0);
printf("Code found in %d attempt(s)!\n",ct);

return 0;
}
```

full working code (portuguese comments and initials)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void){
int c[4],in[4],i,j,ct=0,sc=0,se=0;
srand(time(NULL));

//numeros aleatorios de 1 a 6
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    c[i]=rand()%6+1;
}

do{
    ct++;
    printf("Tentativa: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d",&in[0],&in[1],&in[2],&in[3]);
    //quantos no sitio certo
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
        if(c[j]==in[j])sc++;
    }//quantos que existem repetidos independentemente do sitio
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
        for(i=0;i<4;i++){
            if(c[j]==in[i]){se++;in[i]=0;break;}//podemos alterar o valor do input para 0 porque e alterado repetidamente e nao tem um valor fixo
        }
    }
    se-=sc; //a diferenca destes diz quantos certos estao no sitio errado
    printf("Sitio certo: %d\nSitio errado: %d\n",sc,se);
    if (sc==4) break;
    se=0;sc=0;//repor
}while(0==0);//existe break, nao vale apena criar mais variaveis 
printf("Descoberto em %d tentativa(s)!\n",ct);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what your question is. Try to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to give us - it will be easier to debug than just looking at an incomplete snippet. Also try to give us a more specific problem statement - focus on one variation of the undesired behavior at a time.

Comment: I think you're going to have to describe (or show) more of your code than that if you want any helpful answers. Adding spaces also wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Make a temporary copy of the random array and the input array. When counting the items in the correct position, change the array entries (in both temporary arrays) to 0. When counting items in the wrong position, ignore 0's.

Comment: Your code does not say anything. I suspect it's due to the lack of printf's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this part:

```
for(j=0;j<4;j++){
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        if(c[j]==in[i]){wp++;break;} // problem here
    }
}
```

with your given inputs, both of the '3' input values generate wrong place increments, because there is a `3` in the solution.  As already mentioned, you have to "remove" a 3 from the solution (or account that it has already been checked) once you determine a "right color wrong place" status.

Comment: Instead of getting another array I just changed those two variables like you did, and added inside the if statement "in[i]=0" it does the job. no need to change anything more!